# Prolog - how to understand lists

Tags: prolog

I don't know much, how to understand that fact `p([H|T], H, T)`. I know C/C++/Java etc.. but this looks diferrent. So when i pass first argument to "function" p, it separates it into H and T and makes it accessible through this vars? I don't know how to logically understand this.

> http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/lists.html

```
p([H|T], H, T).


Lets see what happens when we ask some simple queries.

?- p([a,b,c], X, Y).

X=a


Y=[b,c]


yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you refer to says, "Consider the following fact.

`p([H|T], H, T).`"

So we must treat this as a fact. That means, it's like having a predicate

```
p([H|T], H, T):- true.         % or,  p(L,H,T) :- L=[H|T].
```

Now, when you query `p([a,b,c], X, Y).`, one is put besides the other:

```
p([a,b,c], X, Y).              % a query
p([H|T],   H, T) :- true.      % a rule's clause: _head_ :- _body_.
```

the equivalences are noted: `[a,b,c] = [H|T]`, `X = H`, `Y = T` and treated as unification equations. The first gets further translated into

```
a = H                          % list's head element
[b,c] = T                      % list's tail
```

because `[A|B]` stands for a list with `A` the *head* element of the list, and `B` the list's *tail*, i.e. all the rest of its elements, besides the head. `H` and `T` are common mnemonic names for these logical variables.

So on the whole, we get `X = H = a`, `Y = T = [b,c]`.

This process is what's known as *unification* of a query and a rule's head (the two things starting with a `p` "functor", and both having the 3 "arguments").

Since the query and the head of a rule's "clause" matched (had same functor and same number of arguments), and their arguments were all successfully unified, pairwise, using the above *substitution*, we only need to prove the body of that rule's clause (that was thus selected).

Since it is `true`, we immediately succeed, with the successful substitution as our result.

That's how Prolog works.

**TL;DR**: yes, when you call `p(L,H,T)` with a given list `L`, it will be *destructured* into its head `H` and tail `T`. But you may call it with a given list `T`, a value `H`, and a variable `L`, and then a new list will be *constructed* from the head and the tail. And if `L` is given as well, it will be checked whether its head is `H`, and its tail is `T`.

This is because Prolog's unification is bi-directional: `A = B` is the same as `B = A`. Unification with a variable is like setting that variable, and unification with a value is like checking the (structural) equality with that value.

Calling `p(L,H,T)` is really equivalent to the unification `L = [H|T]`.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog we have *relations*, in a way similar to relationals DBs.

Then p/3 it's a *relation* among a *list* (first argument), its head `H` and its tail `T`.

Appropriately the tutorial' author used descriptive and synthetic symbols as Variables.

Syntactically, variables are symbols starting Uppercase and can get *any* value, but *only* one time (that is, cannot be 'reassigned').